# Pig: how to loop through all fields/columns?

Tags: apache-pig

I'm new to Pig. I need to do some calculation for all fields/columns in a table. However, I can't find a way to do it by searching online. It would be great if someone here can give some help!

For example: I have a table with 100 fields/columns, most of them are numeric. I need to find the average of each field/column, is there an elegant way to do it without repeat AVERAGE(column_xxx) for 100 times?

If there's just one or two columns, then I can do

```
B = group A by ALL;
C = foreach B generate AVERAGE(column_1), AVERAGE(columkn_2);
```

However, if there's 100 fields, it's really tedious to repeatedly write AVERAGE for 100 times and it's easy to have errors.

One way I can think of is embed Pig in Python and use Python to generate a string like that and put into compile. However, that still sounds weird even if it works.

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: We use ruby to dynamically generate pig scripts and it works quite well. I don't know of any native pig way to handle it.

Comment: @bridiver : Thanks! How do you pass the column names to the script? Do you store the list of names in an external file and read it? Or is there a way to dynamically get column names from schema?

Comment: I think maybe you are not understanding what I'm saying. The ruby code writes the pig script, which is then sent to pig. How you generate the column names is dependent on what you are doing.

Comment: Sidenote, if you are doing the same thing for 100 columns, consider storing your data differently. If it were stored in list format, you could achieve this with a group by.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pig: is it possible to write a loop over variables in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029980/pig-is-it-possible-to-write-a-loop-over-variables-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a nice way to do this with pig. However, this should work well enough and can be done in 5 minutes:

1. Describe the table (or alias) in question
2. Copy the output, and reorgaize it manually into the script part you need (for example with excel)
3. Finish and store the script

If you need to be able with columns that can suddenly change etc. there is probably no good way to do it in pig. Perhaps you could read it in all columns (in R for example) and do your operation there.